# How to find inductance of a burnt inductor of a RF matching circuit

Tags: inductor, gps

I have an Android headunit for my car with wifi, gps, 3G, etc. At some point the GPS stopped working. I replaced the antenna connector because the pin was bended and could not connect anymore. At the beginning the gps was working for a while and then dead. GPS can see satellites but gets not SNR. I took apart the HU and see that there is a burnt inductor at the matching circuit of an active the antenna (see photo). I think it makes sense that it was working fine but after a while it burnt and had that behaviour. Now it gets no SNR at all. I guess if burnt badly after all.

[image]

Here there are a Ohm resistor (top) , burnt inductor (middle), inductor (bottom right), and a capacitor of 4.7uF (bottom left).

I have the schematics of this, but it corresponds to a part that is "optional" (see schematics).
[image]

I'am no expert at all in electronics, so I need help here. I think that the burnt inductor is M5002, which the description says is 10nH 300mA. The M5003 says nothing, there is no info there. How can I be sure that the burnt one is M5002? (I have no LCR meter at the moment).

Any help will be highly appreciated. 
cheers.

Update 1 :
I am quite sure what is burnt is an inductor see photos attached. [image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7q96.jpg)

Then, @JRE  in this photo it seems as if the empty pad is connected to the antenna pin (I would say GND?)  can you confirm?
[image]

Comment: An LCR meter wouldn't help with a burned out inductor.  If it is burned through, then it no longer has an inductance you could measure.

Comment: An inductor will look like a short circuit when tested with an ohmmeter - very low resistance.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like you bent the connector pin of the external GPS antenna, shorting the center conductor to ground.  Since you say it is an active antenna, you will be looking for an inductor connected to a power source and the antenna cable center conductor.  M5002 connects to ground, so I don't think that's the correct one.

Comment: Do you have a larger section of the schematic, or a link to the whole thing?

Comment: My idea was to measure the inductor that is not burnt and rule out that that is the one of 10nH. Yes, I have more diagrams but I have looked at them and could not figure out that part. For instance, I know that there is more stuff in the picture that I showed (e.g. the capacitor of size 0201) and that is not shown in the diagram. I will add more pictures and

Comment: You'll have to take parts off the board to measure their values.

Comment: Will not be easy, all that board is covered by a shielding metal piece as it is the RF part.I will first try to remove the glue on the pin and see what´s below. That should help.

Answer (score 2):

I removed the glue and figure out some of the parts. But still cannot understand the whole thing. However, I think @JRE is right and the burnt resistor is not M5002 but M5003 as it is the one that carries the line from the antenna, and for which I have no data.  [image]

Update.

After loads of reading I could figure out that the burnt inductor was actually a choke to bring power to the antenna. That's why shortcutting the antenna burnt it. The only function is therefore power, therefore it should block all frequencies in the range if gps antenna, as it was a dedicated gps antenna. The right inductor for the job could be a 27nH (max inductance at 1600MHz).

That's what I did, replace it and now the gps is getting signal again!